# changing the parent of a gtkwidget

Tags: c, gtk

I'm working on a tabbed text editor
what I'm currently trying to do is move the scrolled window holding the text view and move it into a notebook, then add that notebook to the vbox I'm using:

```
gpointer test = g_object_ref(scrolled_window);
        gtk_container_remove((GtkContainer*)vcontainer,scrolled_window);
        gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), scrolled_window, gtk_label_new("untitled document"));
        gtk_box_pack_start((GtkBox*)vcontainer,notebook,1,1,0);
```

the scrolled window gets removed successfully, however the notebook does not show up, no errors or warnings come up either
do i need to force the redrawing of the container or anything of that sort?

Comment: If you are creating the notebook after showing its window, you will need to explicitly call `gtk_widget_show()` or `gtk_widget_show_all()` on the notebook (the latter will call `gtk_window_show()` on all the notebook's pages and all their children).

Comment: You're also leaking the reference you acquired on the scrolled window; the sequence is: ref() → remove() → add() → unref(). remove() will release a reference, and add() will add it back.

Comment: gtk_widget_show_all worked just fine, what do you mean by leaking the reference?

Comment: You correctly called `g_objct_ref()` to save the object from being destroyed when you removed it from the old container. However, every time you add a widget to a container, a reference is taken. Therefore, you need to remove the extra reference that you took to keep the widget alive while you were moving it around. Hopefully that makes more sense.